# Azure - Application Event Log Alerts

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How to create email alerts for Application Event Logs. We can see the event logs from the Diagnostic Tools of the app service but not sure about the email alerts. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

> How to create email alerts for Application Event Logs?

Yes, we can create email alerts for Azure app service using application Insights by following the below steps:

- After creating Application Insights.
- Goto  `Alerts`  under  `Monitoring`  then click on  `create`  and select an  `alert rule`.

[image]

- After creating the alert rule click on  **complete**.
- In alert rules add the condition according to your requirement. In my case i have given condition as  `Whenever the average failed locations is greater than or equal to 2`.
- Now we can fire the alert based on the requirement.
- You can see whether the alert triggered/fired or not in the below screenshot:

[image]

- You will receive an email alert to the email ID which you have configured in the above steps like below screenshot:

[image]

***References:-***

[Send alerts from Azure Application Insights - Azure Monitor | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/tutorial-alert).

[Monitor application via Application Insights and send alert](https://dev.to/kenakamu/monitor-application-via-application-insights-part-1-set-rule-and-action-45k4).

Comment: Thanks Rajkumar for your answer, but I am looking for application event log of the app service and I couldn't find any metrices for the same.